# Вывод максимального числа в последовательности

Tags: java

Задание заключается в следующем: напишите программу, которая считывает последовательность целочисленных значений из стандартного вывода и находит максимальное из них. Уточнение:

1. Вы должны считывать значения последовательности, пока следующее не станет 0. Нулевое значение означает конец входной последовательности и не является ее элементом.
2. Последовательность гарантированно содержит хотя бы одно значение.

   ```
   public class FindMaxInSeq {
   public static int max() {
       Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
       int maxSoFar=0 ;
       int currValue;
       do {
           currValue = scnr.nextInt();
           if (currValue > maxSoFar ) {
               maxSoFar = currValue;
           }
       } while (currValue != 0);

       return maxSoFar;
   }
       public static void main (String[]args){

           System.out.println("Test your code here!\n");

           FindMaxInSeq test = new FindMaxInSeq();

           System.out.println(max());
       }
   }
   ```

Код работает, но не полностью, при вводе отрицательного числа и 0 выводит ноль, а должно быть наоборот.
Пример-ввод: -966598
0
вывод: 0. А должно быть -966598. **Заранее спасибо**

Comment: Значит, `maxSoFar=0 ;` не годится, не так ли?

Comment: Да, так как 0 по условию, ето выход из последовательности и не должен быть ее элементом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в инициализации переменной. Решить можно кучей способов, например так:

```
public class FindMaxInSeq {
    public static int max() {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        int currValue = scnr.nextInt();
        int maxSoFar=currValue;
        while (true) {
            currValue = scnr.nextInt();
            if(currValue==0)break;
            if (currValue >= maxSoFar ) {
                maxSoFar = currValue;
            }
        }

        return maxSoFar;
    }
    public static void main (String[]args){

        System.out.println("Test your code here!\n");

        FindMaxInSeq test = new FindMaxInSeq();

        System.out.println(max());
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, нашел в себе то чему нужно уделить внимание.